# How to optimize SQL in Python

Tags: mysql, python-3.x, moodle

first sorry my english :(
I am making a Python program accessing information from moodle. But the access to the server's sql is very slow, I needed to optimize the sql like the one below:

```
    try:
        query1 = "SELECT id FROM mdl_user WHERE username= ('%s')" % (self.searchuser2)
        cursor.execute(query1)
        linhas = cursor.fetchall()
        for row in linhas:
            self.userid = row[0]
        # Pegando enrol_id do curso
        query2 = "SELECT id FROM mdl_enrol WHERE courseid = %s AND enrol = 'manual'" % (self.rowidcourse)
        cursor.execute(query2)
        linhas = cursor.fetchall()
        for row in linhas:
            self.enrol_courseid = row[0]

        # Inserindo o aluno e curso em mdl_user_enrolments
        query3 = "INSERT INTO mdl_user_enrolments (status, enrolid, userid, timestart, timeend, timecreated, timemodified) VALUES(0, %s, %s, 1, 0, 1, 1)" % (
            self.enrol_courseid, self.userid)
        cursor.execute(query3)
        mariadb_connection.commit()

        # Pegando contex_id do curso e aluno
        query4 = "SELECT id FROM mdl_context WHERE instanceid=%s AND contextlevel=50" % (self.rowidcourse)
        cursor.execute(query4)
        linhas = cursor.fetchall()
        for row in linhas:
            self.contexid = row[0]
        # Inserindo aluno no curso
        query5 = "INSERT INTO mdl_role_assignments (roleid,contextid,userid,timemodified) VALUES (5,%s,%s,2000)" \
                 % (self.contexid, self.userid)
        cursor.execute(query5)
        mariadb_connection.commit()
        closedb()
        tkinter.messagebox.showinfo("Muito bem!", "Aluno cadastrado com sucesso.", parent=self.register1)
```

Comment: Do you know which statement is the slowest?  You can place basic timers around each call to see which is taking the longest.
https://realpython.com/python-timer/#python-timers
Can you provide the execution plan?  `EXPLAIN SQL`
The inserts are probably not the issue.  From my first glance, it looks like queries 2 and 4 could be combined

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are enrolling all users into all courses? That's potentially a lot of data.

You are also getting all records from `mdl_enrol` for each loop of `mdl_user`.

And `enrolid` isn't the same as `courseid`. `Enrolid` is in `mdl_enrol`.

The code also doesn't check if the data already exists.

Also Moodle has lots of triggers that won't be activated by this code.

It might be better to have a look at Site Admin > Users > Upload users

https://docs.moodle.org/39/en/Upload_users#Enrolment_fields

This will allow you to enrol users into multiple courses.

Comment: Not exactly, I am enrolling only one user in the course.

In `mdl_enrol`, I'm just taking the id of the specific course. (I ended up changing them all to `fetchone` and just taking the first one which gave me a little more performance)

I don't need to check if the student already exists in the course because that part comes right after the student's user creation.

Unfortunately I cannot use moodle directly because I am making an application for school franchises that do not have access to the server administrator.